# Graph involving moment of inertia

Tags: calculus

Suppose we are calculating moment of inertia of a uniform rod with linear density $\lambda$ and length $L$.Now the total moment of inertia of the rod is $\frac{ML^2}{12}$ which we find by integrating.Now the total moment of inertia must be the area under some curve as the definition of integral is the area under the curve.My question is what is that curve(I mean the function and the independent variable)?Could you please show the graph?Also should we think of integrals as area under the curve always or continuos sums?

Comment: See the first example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Examples_2)

Comment: I am sorry,but how does that answer my question?I asked for the curve and graph

Comment: You can't graph $x\mapsto x^2$?

Comment: Why is that function f(x)=x^2?Could you please show me the graph of the moment of inertia and validate the x^2 function?

Comment: Moment of inertia about an axis $\ell$ is defined as the integral $I(\ell)=\int\operatorname{distance}(\mathbf{x},\ell)^2\,\mathrm{d}m(\mathbf{x})$.

Comment: You still don't seem to get my question